# Why does domain/folder/ and domain/folder///// return the same location?

Tags: apache-2.2, rewrite, url, firefox

Why does domain/folder/ and domain/folder///// return the same location in a browser's URL address bar?

Windows 7 + Firefox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

POSIX compliance says that multiple /'s are collapsed into one.